# Get actual object location in animation handler

Tags: animation, scripting

I have found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5636/how-can-i-get-the-location-of-an-object-at-each-keyframe) answer, but it works not inside animation handler.
Is it possible to get and print object locations (`xyz`) from animation handler (`frame_change_pre`) ?

```
def my_handler(scene):
    ob = bpy.data.objects["ob_1"]
    pos = ob.location
    print(pos)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

In example above location didn't changed from frame to frame.

Comment: Your code works for an object called `"ob_1"` and a keyframed `location`. Do you use a driver or e.g. an armature that changes the translation of the object? If so, use `ob.matrix_world.translation` instead.

Comment: yes, object ob_1 works in animation and keyframed by location. ob.matrix_world.translation shows location with different Z locations from frame to frame as expected. Many thanks